# How to consume the Google+ API without any client interaction

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to perform some read-only requests against the Google+ API - mainly to read some Activities. This is a server only application - no browser and no client interaction.

I have been reading throuh the various types of authentication the Google APIs support and I am relativelly certain that my usecase maps to the **[Service Account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount) scenario** - so I have been looking at this sample: [plus-serviceaccount-cmdline-sample](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/plus-serviceaccount-cmdline-sample/instructions.html).

Now, I have created a new Application (in the Google APIs console), created Service Account credentials, and generally followed the instructions of the sample. 
I am however getting:

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong - any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way to get an "invalid_grant" error with the service account sample is forgetting to insert the registered email address into your code.

Go to https://developers.google.com/console, then to API Access and look where you registered your service account.

You should see a field labeled that looks like

```
Email address: XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

You need to copy this value and insert it into

```
plus-serviceaccount-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/plus/serviceaccount/cmdline/PlusServiceAccountSample.java
```

In the line as follows:

```
/** E-mail address of the service account. */
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "Enter service account e-mail from "
    + "https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=plus into SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL in "
    + PlusServiceAccountSample.class;
```

So that it looks like this:

```
/** E-mail address of the service account. */
private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
```

This, and downloading the .p12 key into the project are crucial for the application to authenticate.

Comment: Thanks for the help - that did the trick. I was using my main email address instead of that one.